# Expand datagrid's container when content in column changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i've got a DataGrid w/ 3 columns.  the first column cell is a Combo from which the user can select values of varying length.  i would like the first column to display the entire value of the selected item (i.e. it should size to fit its content).  this works when i set the column's Width="Auto".   the problem is at some point, when the entire width of the grid is taken up, and the scroll bar appears. instead i would rather the datagrid itself always expand, and consequently its containers.  how can i do this..
the structure of my xaml is as follows

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <local:MyUserControl... Grid.Col="1">
    <Expander Grid.Column="2">
        <GroupBox  Template="{Binding OptionsSelectorTemplate}" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Expander
</Grid>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="OptionsSelectorTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <dxl:NavBarControl...>
            <dxn:NavBarControl.Groups>
                <dxn:NavBarGroup Header="Options Set 1">
                    <DataGrid Style="{StaticResource DataGridTemplateStyle}" ItemSource="{Binding ViewModel.Options}" DataContext="{Binding .}"/>
                </dxn:NavBarGroup>
                <dxn:NavBarGroup Header="Options Set 2">
                    <DataGrid Style="{StaticResource DataGridTemplateStyle}" ItemSource="{Binding ViewModel.Options}" DataContext="{Binding .}"/>
                </dxn:NavBarGroup>
        </dxl:NavBarControl...>
        <Button ... />
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="DataGridTemplateStyle" TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource DataGridTemplate}" />
</Style>     

<ControlTemplate x:Key="DataGridTemplate">
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <DataGrid Name="_dataGrid" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" HeadersVisibility="Column" CanUserAddRows="False" GridLinesVisibility="None" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Col1" MinWidth="75" Width="Auto" KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox.../>  <---Want this guy to size to always fit the selected list item and to expand the entire datagrid if need be w/o displaying horizontal scroll bar.
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Weight" MinWidth="40"  >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border >
                                <TextBox T../>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="NN" Width="30">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox .../>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like as per documentation, DataGrid columns only resize in one direction..that is they only get wider, not narrower.